# default time zone is not changing using php or php.ini

Tags: php, timezone

i'm trying to change the default time zone using php but not working

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Riyadh')
```

and tried using php.ini

```
date.timezone="Asia/Riyadh"
```

but in phpinfo i get this

```
Default timezone    Europe/Berlin
date.timezone   Europe/Berlin   Europe/Berlin
```

and when inserting time to MySQL using CURTIME() i don't get Asia/Riyadh time and get a wrong time
update (timezone changed after awhile but using CURTIME() to insert date into mysql doesn't enter the right time

Comment: did you change the right .ini file? `phpinfo()` output will tell you which .ini file(s) are being used. did you restart the webserver after changing it? and changing PHP settings will *NOT* change how mysql processes times. curtime() is a mysql function and will use mysql timezone settings.

Comment: i've uploaded the file in the root directory of the site

Comment: unless php's been told to look for a .ini file there, that will do nothing.

Comment: the path to the php.ini is correct

Comment: If you put `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Riyadh');` in a PHP script, it's only good for the execution of that script.

Comment: Have you restarted the server after updating the .ini?

Comment: i can't restart the server and it should be working without a restart i had made many changes in php.ini and worked without restarting

Comment: I just checked on my server and the timezone doesn't update until the server was restarted. What server are you using and what version of PHP.

Comment: OK solved half of the prblem but still entering the wrong date into mysql while timezone changed to Asia/Riyadh

Comment: What timezone is you SQL using?

Comment: I think with MYSQL you can check with `SHOW Variables like 'system_time_zone'`

Comment: Thanks all for your interest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in php.ini

```
date.timezone="Asia/Riyadh"
```

and in my script

```
$nowtime = date("G:i:s");
$nowdate = date("Y-m-d");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must always restart your server when making any changes to your php.ini file.

Another thing to look into if you are positive that you are updating the correct .ini file is to look at the "Additional .ini files parsed" in your phpinfo(). Sometimes you will find that certain programs or updates may add additional files here and it will override your php.ini settings.